# How to get value from textbox controls in Repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have repeater with item template:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpGiaiThuong">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="giaithuong">
      <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("MaGiaiThuong")%>' />
      <input type="checkbox" value='<%#Eval("MaGiaiThuong")%>' id='<%#Eval("MaGiaiThuong")%>' />
      <span><%#Eval("TenGiaiThuong")%> </span>
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtGiaTri" CssClass="form-control">                 
      </asp:TextBox>
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

How can I Get ID of TextBox at codebehind (c#)?

Comment: [FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) will likely give you that.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rpGiaiThuong.Items)
{
      TextBox txtName = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtGiaTri");
      if(txtName!=null)
      {
      //do something with txtName.Text
      }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Even for this question?